# Needs entry point of a package from a Mathematica script

Tags: packages, scripting

I am writing a bunch of *Mathematica* scripts to run command line in a HPC environment. I am organising my solution in small chunks I can test separately. So I have a directory structure like:

```
├── test
│   ├── coefficients-test.math
│   ├── main-test.math
│   ├── nearest-test.math
│   ├── rangek-test.math
│   ├── unit.m
│   └── wave-test.math
└── wde
    ├── coefficients.m
    ├── ???.m
    ├── nearest.m
    ├── rangek.m
    └── wave.m
```

The `test` folder contains a bunch of unit tests using simple poor man's testing. Each test script begins (say `test/coefficients-test`)

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script

$Path = Join[$Path, {Directory[]<>"/wde"}];
Needs["unit`"];
Needs["coefficients`"];
```

and then testing code. I `chmod`ed them with a+x and I just run them like:

> $ ./test/coefficients-test.math

(Needless to say that in the HPC the *Mathematica* script path is different, but that is secondary for the moment.)

So far so good. The problem is that when I try to develop the main component of my `wde` package, if I name the file `wde/init.m` or `wde/wde.m` or `wde/Kernel/init.m` and try to load it in the test script with `` Needs["wde`"] `` I get the infamous context not created error; although I have inside it `` BeginPackage["wde`"] ``.

If I name my package, say `wde/main.m` and put inside `` BeginPackage["main`"] ``, it works.

Easy work around, but I was wondering what I am doing wrong in the first place.

Do I need to copy my package to a standard *Mathematica* location for script loading? Why doesn't the `$Path` trick work in this case?

Again, this is a purely scripting approach - not sure if this is suitable from the front-end in a notebook, although at this stage this not a concern. Actually, my plan is to develop the script further to [generate a CDF via a script](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-cdf-virtual-workshop-2012/videos/real-world-applications/) and load that in the front-end for demo-ing purposes, etc (I understand this is the recommended solution to CDF production.)

Comment: How does the `BeginPackage` command looks inside your `wde.m` when the message appears? Please try the following: Append to your `$Path` only `Directory[]`, without the `wde` sub-dir. In your `wde.m` you define ``BeginPackage["wde`"]`` and in your `Kernel/init.m` you use ``Get["wde`wde`"]``.